# How to allow anonymous users to sign in to Kooboo?

Tags: user-accounts, anonymous-access, kooboo

What do I need to do so that I could allow anonymous users to be able to create an account when I'm using Kooboo CMS?

Comment: Why is that off topic? Do people who closed that question know Kooboo? He can't do that without developing his own module/plugin so it is a progamming question

Comment: While it is a very poor quality question, with little detail, examples or external references, it is still in my opinion a valid question.  Until such time as the Area 51 Kooboo site launches (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79383/kooboo), the main Stack Overflow site seems the perfect place for this question.